# Varying the Einstein-Hilbert action when matter fields are off-shell

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory

The Einstein-Hilbert action reads
\begin{equation*}
S_{EH} = \int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}R + \mathcal{L}_M(\phi,g)\bigg)
\end{equation*}
where $\phi$ are the matter fields and $\mathcal{L}_M$ is the matter Lagrangian. Varying the action with respect to the metric gives the Einstein equations:
\begin{equation*}
G_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation*}
What is peculiar to me about this is that at this point we have not assumed that the matter fields are on-shell. However, if the matter fields are off-shell, we might not expect $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu} = 0$ to hold identically. Since $\nabla_{\mu} G^{\mu\nu} = 0$ is a purely geometric identity, it should not be possible for the EFEs to hold in this case.

My question is thus: what is the interpretation of this apparent inconsistency of the saddle-point equations in a scenario where the matter fields are off-shell? Is this inconsistency telling us that there is no saddle, i.e. that the action is unbounded below or that that the 'minimum' occurs at a singular/otherwise pathological metric configuration?

Comment: The saddle "point" in this case is a field configuration where all fields are specified and obey the classical equations of motion, so the matter fields will be on shell at the saddle point.

Comment: Pretend that instead of treating the fields as dynamical variables I treat them as fixed source terms (so now I have an action that is badly broken in terms of translation invariance etc.). It still makes sense to vary the action with respect to the metric in this situation and ask what the resultant evolution looks like-- this is what I am going for here.

Comment: Echoing Andrew's above comment: There is no physical scenario where the matter fields are off-shell.

Comment: This is principally a mathematical question rather than a physical question, which I think should have an answer regardless of interpretation. But, to be more concrete: the scenario that motivated this question was as an approximation to the gravitational path integral, where the integral over matter fields would be taken as normal but the inner integral over gravitational degrees of freedom would be approximated by the highest amplitude saddle conditioned on the outer configuration of the matter fields. For this you would want to compute the saddle I am describing above.

Comment: If the matter fields are off shell, $T_{\mu\nu}$ is generally not conserved. But that does not imply any inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your problem has little to do with gravity. You could voice a similar concern with electromagnetism. In this case:
$$
\mathcal L = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\mathcal L_M(A,\phi)
$$
The simplest example would be:
$$
\mathcal L_M(A,\phi) = |(i\partial -qA)\phi|^2-V(|\phi|^2)
$$
Similarly, varying the EM field $A$ you’d get:
$$
j^\mu := \frac{\delta S_M}{\delta A_\mu} \\
j^\mu=\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}
$$
giving automatically the conservation of charge:
$$
\partial_\mu j^\mu=0
$$
Here, the analogue of the Einstein tensor is $\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}$. Similarly, the property:
$$
\partial_\mu\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=0
$$
is purely “geometric”. In either case, the conclusion is the same. Conservation laws only requires the gauge field to be on shell.

To reconcile with your approach, you must realize that the conserved currents depend on the gauge field as well. Take the previous example:
$$
j^\mu= -q(\phi^*(i\partial-qA)\phi+hc)
$$
This can be traced back to the interaction between the gauge field and the matter field. Therefore, the conservation of the currents is not incompatible with the matter fields be off shell. Since the gauge fields are on shell, they depend implicitly on the matter fields through the Euler Lagrange equations. This dependence in the matter field allows the resulting currents to be conserved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to LPZ's answer to show how the conservation equation arises from the "gauge symmetry" in the game. Gravity can be thought of as a gauge theory where the gauge group is all the possible diffeomorphisms. We expect the theory to be invariant under diffeomorphisms ($\delta S = 0$). Under an infinitesimal diffeomorphism $\xi$, the metric changes as

$$ g_{ab}'= g_{ab} + (\mathcal{L}_{\xi}g)_{ab} + ...$$

where $\mathcal{L}_{\xi}g$ is the Lie derivative of the metric. In terms of covariant derivative this can be written as

$$ g_{ab}'= g_{ab} + \nabla_a\xi_b + \nabla_b\xi_a + \mathcal{O}(\xi^2)$$

Now consider the full action of GR which is

$$ S = S_{EH} + S_{matter}$$

Now vary the metric as $g_{ab} \rightarrow g_{ab} + \delta g_{ab}$ for some variation $\delta g_{ab}$. he variation of the full metric is

$$ \delta S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left[\frac{\delta S_{EH}}{\delta g_{ab}(\mathcal{x}) } +  \frac{\delta S_{matter}}{\delta g_{ab}(\mathcal{x}) }\right]\delta g_{ab}$$

Now suppose we pick a $g$ such that it minimises $S_{EH}$. We now have

$$\delta S = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left[ \frac{\delta S_{matter}}{\delta g_{ab}(\mathcal{x}) }\right]\delta g_{ab}$$

Finally, consider a small diffeomorphism where $\delta g_{ab} = \nabla_a\xi_b + \nabla_b\xi_a$. We expect the theory to be invariant under these transformations. Therefore $\delta S = 0$. Using the definition of the energy momentum tensor $T^{ab}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{matter}}{\delta g_{ab}(x)}$, we have

$$\delta S = \frac{1}{2}\int d^4x T^{ab} (\nabla_a\xi_b + \nabla_b\xi_a) = \int d^4x T^{ab} \nabla_a\xi_b = 0$$

Where in the second line, I used the symmetry of the energy momentum tensor. Integrating this equation by parts, we arrive at the key equation.

$$\int d^4x \nabla_a T^{ab}\xi_b = 0$$

If this is to hold for all $\xi_b$, we must have $\nabla_a T^{ab} = 0$. Therefore the conservation of energy momentum tensor is directly implied by diffeomorphism invariance.

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for I think, but one thing that seems off to me is that the variation of the whole action with respect to the metric should be zero, not just the EH part -- otherwise aren't the equations for g just the vacuum Einstein equations, no?

Comment: You are right I cheated a little bit. However, the crux of the argument is the fact that you require matter lagrangian to be diffeomorphism invariant. This is actually how you define the energy momentum tensor in minkowski field theories as well (but then set g to minkowski spacetime)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this inconsistency telling us that there is no saddle

Firstly, it’s not an inconsistency, as I’ll hopefully convince you below. Next, instead of “saddle”, you should say “critical point”. But yes, if you turn out to get a matter field $\phi$ such that for all $g$, $T_{\mu\nu}[\phi,g]$ which has non-zero divergence, then there is no solution to the field equations, or equivalently, for a fixed $\phi$ the action does not admit a critical point with respect to variations of the metric. So, it’s all an existence issue.

As a simpler example (actually I can come up with even more trivial examples, but hopefully this illustrates the point), let’s consider the function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y)=y+\frac{y^3}{3}-xy$. Let us consider fixing $x_0$ and finding critical points as a function of $y$. So, we set the $y$-partial derivative equal to zero, and we see that this is satisfied by a point $(x_0,y)$ if and only if $1+y^2-x_0=0$, or equivalently, $1+y^2=x_0$. Notice that clearly, if $x_0<1$, then there are no solutions in $y$. That’s just the way it is. If $x_0=1$, we have a unique solution $y$, and if $x_0>1$, then we have two solutions for $y$. So, the existence and uniqueness of critical points with respect to variations in $y$ depends on the $x_0$ we have.

It’s the same story with your situation, just that instead of $f(x,y)$, you have the action $S[\phi,g]$, and instead of trying to solve the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y)=0$ for $y$, you’re trying to solve for $\frac{\delta S}{\delta g}[\phi_0,g]=0$ for $g$, which is equivalent to $G_{\mu\nu}[g]=8\pi T_{\mu\nu}[\phi_0,g]$. As you rightly point out, for some $\phi_0$’s, the RHS is such that for all $g$, the divergence is non-zero, and thus, one can never find a metric $g$ which satisfies the equation, and hence considering the action as a function of the metric only, $g\mapsto S[\phi_0,g]$, it admits no critical points. For example, you can look at Einstein-Hilbert coupled with a massless scalar field.

Here’s a silly (non?)example. Note that you could also formally try to consider the Einstein-Hilbert functional $g\mapsto \int_{S^2}R\,dA_g$, where $g$ is a Lorentzian metric on the sphere $S^2$. Of course this has nothing to do with gravity, but mathematically it may seem like a perfectly reasonable functional to come up with. You could naively work out the equations of motion, but then you may remember that oh no, the sphere $S^2$ doesn’t admit a Lorentzian metric, so all of this is vacuous.

So, when coming up with good equations, you impose certain conditions on the matter Lagrangian (e.g how it plays nicely with diffeomorphisms, as mentioned in the other answer), and then you see that when the matter equations of motion are satisfied (if they even admit solutions), the resulting stress tensor is divergence-free, so the resulting field equation $G_{\mu\nu}=8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$ atleast doesn’t have the divergence inconsistency. A-priori, this of course still doesn’t tell us anything about existence of a $g$ which satisfies this equation (for that one can defer to Yvonne-Choquet Bruhat’s well-posedness statement).